# NestJS creating Custom Decorator (checking wether Base64 Content Is Image)

Tags: nestjs, class-validator

## following file was working and after couple of months it stopped. returns error.

This is what is placed on my property in the DTO
@Base64ContentIsImage(
'logoContentType',
Object.values(OrganizationLogoMimeTypes),
)
here i have provided the function which is used in the DTO

```
import {
  ValidationArguments,
  ValidationOptions,
  ValidatorConstraint,
  ValidatorConstraintInterface,
  registerDecorator,
} from 'class-validator';
import { OrganizationLogoMimeTypes } from '../../../domain/models/organization.model';
import { CreateOrganizationDto } from '../dtos/create-organization.dto';
import { UpdateOrganizationDto } from '../dtos/update-organization.dto';

export function Base64ContentIsImage(
  property: string,
  acceptedContentTypes?: string[],
  validationOptions?: ValidationOptions,
) {
  return (
    object: UpdateOrganizationDto | CreateOrganizationDto,
    propertyName: string,
  ) => {
    registerDecorator({
      target: object.constructor,
      propertyName,
      options: validationOptions,
      constraints: [property, acceptedContentTypes],
      validator: Base64ContentIsImageConstraint,
    });
  };
}

@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'Base64ContentIsImage' })
export class Base64ContentIsImageConstraint
  implements ValidatorConstraintInterface
{
  async validate(value: string, args: ValidationArguments) {
    const [contentTypePropertyName] = args.constraints;
    const acceptedContentTypes = args.constraints[1];
    const contentType = (
      args.object as UpdateOrganizationDto | CreateOrganizationDto
    )[contentTypePropertyName];
    const decodedContent = Buffer.from(value, 'base64');
    if (contentType === OrganizationLogoMimeTypes.SVG) {
      const isSvg = (await import('is-svg')).default;
      return isSvg(decodedContent.toString());
    } else {
      const fileTypeFromBuffer = (await import('file-type')).fileTypeFromBuffer;
      const mimeType = (await fileTypeFromBuffer(decodedContent))?.mime;
      return mimeType && acceptedContentTypes.includes(mimeType);
    }
  }

  defaultMessage() {
    return `Image content is not valid `;
  }
}
```